# Javascript alert not working on website

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit, alert

I have tried several different things in javascript but nothing seems to work on my site. I'm trying to have an alert pop up when submitting a form. This is what I have

```
<form>
    Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name" required><br>
    Email:<br>
    <input type="email" name="email" required><br>
    Phone (Format: 999-999-9999):<br>
    <input type="tel" name="phone" required pattern="\d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}"><br>
    Nature of comment:<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="comment" value="Question"> Question
    <input type="checkbox" name="comment" value="Business Inquiry"> Business Inquiry
    <input type="checkbox" name="comment" value="Comment"> Comment
    <input type="checkbox" name="comment" value="Other"> Other <br>
    Comment:<br>
    <textarea></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <form onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?');">
</form>
```

This is the website: http://webpages.uncc.edu/~kjardine/MC_Portfolio/contact.html

Comment: Try placing the onsubmit in the top form element.

Comment: Your HTML isn't valid. Form elements should not be nested, and the inner form doesn't have a closing tag anyway.

Comment: That's it! Thank you!

Comment: Check the rest of your HTML too. You're starting the `<body>` well into the page content.

Comment: The form is the only thing on my page. I'm not sure what you mean that they shouldn't be nested. Also this is a single form, so I don't know what you mean by inner form either.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there, the key is the code you have already has a `<form>` tag which starts on line 1, so you should add your `onsubmit=""` attribute into that one. Here is the revised code that should do the trick:

```
<form onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?');">
    Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name" required><br>
    Email:<br>
    <input type="email" name="email" required><br>
    Phone (Format: 999-999-9999):<br>
    <input type="tel" name="phone" required pattern="\d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}"><br>
    Nature of comment:<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="comment" value="Question"> Question
    <input type="checkbox" name="comment" value="Business Inquiry"> Business Inquiry
    <input type="checkbox" name="comment" value="Comment"> Comment
    <input type="checkbox" name="comment" value="Other"> Other <br>
    Comment:<br>
    <textarea></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The onsubmit should go in the form element at the top, like the commenter said.  and the form element its in currently should be deleted.

That said, you could also have checked a "dont show any more popups" option once for that website, and now popups will be disabled until you enable the popups again, by clearing your chrome cache for instance.

```
<form onsubmit="return confirm('u sure?');">
    <input>...
</form>
```

I also advise against using onsubmit as an HTML parameter, and instead writing a js handler in an actual `<script></script` block to do the confirm.

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = function onSubmit(form) {
        return confirm('u sure?');
    }
}
```

Remember to add `id="myForm"` to your form element in this case.